# Javascript Menu tree not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tree

I am pretty sure that the solution is very simple but I have been at this for hours without being able to work it out. Sometimes we just need an extra pair of eyes.

I have made a function to display a menu in Javascript. It works by clicking on the menu item, if that item has children, the link doesn't work but shows the children instead. This should happen all the way down the tree. There is no problem with that part, the problem is that when on items children are visible, clicking on another item in the main menu should make the children of the other item disappear. This is where I am having problems.

Html:

```
<div class="nav nav-default">
  <ul class="site-menu wm-site-menu">
    <li id="page_9526"><a href="/wm/f/foretaget" target="_parent"     title="Företaget">Företaget</a></li>
    <li id="page_9529"><a href="/wm/f/produkter" target="_parent" title="Produkter">Produkter</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li id="page_9547"><a href="/wm/f/traktorer" target="_parent" title="Traktorer">Traktorer</a></li>
        <li id="page_9548"><a href="/wm/f/lastmaskiner" target="_parent" title="Lastmaskiner">Lastmaskiner</a>
          <ul class="visible" style="display: block;">
            <li id="page_9727"><a href="/wm/f/kompaktlastare" target="_parent" title="Kompaktlastare">Kompaktlastare</a></li>
            <li id="page_9723"><a href="/wm/f/hjullastare" target="_parent" title="Hjullastare">Hjullastare</a></li>
            <li id="page_9724"><a href="/wm/f/teleskophjullastare" target="_parent" title="Teleskophjullastare">Teleskophjullastare</a></li>
            <li id="page_9725"><a href="/wm/f/teleskoplastare" target="_parent" title="Teleskoplastare">Teleskoplastare</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="page_9533"><a href="/wm/f/begagnat" target="_parent" title="Begagnat">Begagnat</a>
    <ul class="" style="display: none;">
      <li id="page_9534"><a href="/wm/f/maskiner" target="_parent" title="Maskiner">Maskiner</a></li>
      <li id="page_9535"><a href="/wm/f/begagnade-traktorer" target="_parent" title="Traktorer">Traktorer</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="wm-menu-active" id="page_9515"><a href="/wm/f/verkstad" target="_parent" title="Verkstad">Verkstad</a></li>
   <li id="page_9532"><a href="/wm/f/butik-och-reservdelar" target="_parent" title="Butik &amp; Reservdelar">Butik &amp; Reservdelar</a></li>
   <li id="page_9525"><a href="/wm/f/kontakt" target="_parent" title="Kontakt">Kontakt</a>        
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-default li').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(e){
      if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();   
        $('.site-menu li ul li').on('click', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
        });

        if($(this).children('ul').hasClass('visible')){        
          $(this).children('ul').removeClass('visible');
          $(this).children('ul').hide();
        }
        else{
          var child_with_children = $(this).children('ul');
          child_with_children.show();
          child_with_children.addClass('visible');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/98CxJ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-default li').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(e){
          $(this).siblings().children('ul').fadeOut().removeClass('visible');
      if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();   
        $('.site-menu li ul li').on('click', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
        });

        if($(this).children('ul').hasClass('visible')){        
          $(this).children('ul').removeClass('visible');
          $(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
        }
        else{
          var child_with_children = $(this).children('ul');
          child_with_children.fadeIn();
          child_with_children.addClass('visible');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That works a lot better now. One problem left. If I open up lastmaskiner and then click on begagnat, then click on produkter, the children of lastmaskiner are visible.

Comment: But it appears that you intentionally set this as 'visible' in your initial code, and hence i followed

Comment: Do you mean that if I swap the content of the if and the else 'if($(this).children('ul').hasClass('visible'))' the that should solve the problem?

Comment: Ok, fixed the problem with the extra line $(this).siblings().children('ul').children().find('.visible').removeClass('visible').hide();